# How to count multiple column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to count the number of 0:2 in multiple columns of my data. Here is a sample. Thank for everyone.

```
df <- data_frame(
  a = sample(0:2, 10, replace=T), 
  b = sample(0:2, 10, replace=T), 
  c = sample(0:2, 10, replace=T), 
  d = sample(0:2, 10, replace=T), 
)
```

I want to got like this output

| score | a | b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 | 4 | 3 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | 5 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 6 | 1 | 5 | 5 |

Comment: `table(stack(df))`

Answer (score 2):

#### Code

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(),values_to = "score") %>% 
  count(name,score) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name,values_from = n,values_fill = 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate using `purrr::map()` to `dplyr::count()` by each column, then use `purrr::reduce()` to `dplyr::left_join()` all the result dataframes together.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
set.seed(13)

counts <- map(
  names(df),
  ~ count(df, score = .data[[.x]], name = .x)
)

reduce(counts, left_join)
```

```
  score a b c d
1     0 4 5 3 2
2     1 4 1 2 5
3     2 2 4 5 3
```